# android webview camera on local network permissions

Tags: android, webview, android-permissions, local

I am building an android webview app to work offline pointing to a local server, its working as in loading the local website from http://123.456.7.8/mywebsite, only part that isnt is the camera.

I believe this is a permissions issue as it works when pointed to the same site thats online which uses https.

I will have full access to the hardware being used if there is an option in developer mode to allow unsecure connections access, similar to the flags in chrome.

mainActivty.java

```
private void checkCameraPermission() {
    int writeExternalStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    if (writeExternalStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1001);
    }
}

public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
    final String[] requestedResources = request.getResources();
    for (String r : requestedResources) {
        if (r.equals(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE)) {
            request.grant(new String[]{PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE});
            break;
        }
    }
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
   mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
   mywebView.loadUrl("http://123.456.7.89/mywebsite");
   WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
   WebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

   mywebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
     @Override
     public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) {
         request.grant(request.getResources());
     }
   });
}
```

androidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
 
 <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
 </application>
```